# What's the use of Broadcast state in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink

I'm not asking what the broadcast pattern is for, but the broadcast state specifically. In both [this example](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/03/24/demo-fraud-detection-2.html) and [this one](https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/26/broadcast-state.html), whenever the broadcasted elements are processed, they are added/put to a BroadcastState:

```
    public void processBroadcastElement(
     Pattern pattern, 
     Context ctx, 
     Collector<Tuple2<Long, Pattern>> out) throws Exception 
{
   // store the new pattern by updating the broadcast state
   BroadcastState<Void, Pattern> bcState = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternDesc);
   // storing in MapState with null as VOID default value
   bcState.put(null, pattern);
 }
```

Suppose that instead of doing that, we added the Pattern to a local List or HashMap. What would be the problem with that? The documentation says that it's important that each parallel instance keeps the its own BroadcastState in the same way as the other instances, so that when rescaling happens, deterministic behavior is achieved. But in this case each parallel instance will always need all the Patterns, so whatever happens at rescaling is irrelevant.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using local state, rather than state managed by Flink, is that it won't be fault tolerant. Of course, if the broadcast state is static, it might not be difficult to reload it yourself during a restart. But in the general case, it's convenient to have the broadcast state stored along with the rest of the state being managed by Flink, in one consistent state store. Especially if the broadcast state is being continuously updated.

Comment: Thank you David. Your answers are always helpful.